# If - else condition in XML View UI5 application

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

In my XML view for one of the fields I want to display "Yes" if value from Model parts is "S" or "P" and for rest of all the values want to display "No".

```
text="{= ${order>/parts} === 'S' ? "Yes" : ${order>/parts} === 'P' ? "Yes" : "No} }"/>
```

Also, how to write - 
`if ${order>/parts}` has "S" `AND ${order>/stock}` has "A" then display Yes else No in the similar notion like above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this small example and it works just fine. Maybe because you use double quotes in both opening the text property and at the values ("Yes" and "No"). Try replacing the `"` with `'` in your values. If that doesn't work, you should check if `{order>/parts}` is not undefined.

**View**

```
<Input value="{= ${test1} === 'S' ? 'Yes' : ${test1} === 'P' ? 'Yes' : 'No'}" />
<Input value="{= ${test1} === 'S' ? ${test2} === 'P' ? 'Yes' : 'No' : 'No' }" />
```

or

```
<Input value="{= ${test1} === 'S' || ${test1} === 'P' ? 'Yes' : 'No'}" />
<Input value="{= ${test1} === 'S'  &amp;&amp; ${test2} === 'P' ? 'Yes' : 'No'}"/>
```

**Controller**

```
    onInit: function() {
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
            test1: "S",
            test2: "P"
        });

        var bindingContext = new sap.ui.model.Context();
        bindingContext.oModel = oModel;
        bindingContext.sPath = "/";

        this.getView().setBindingContext(bindingContext);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    }
```

Comment: yes it works with ' instead of  ".  Also, any suggestions for the AND case?

Comment: I added the AND case as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @Matthijs.

Answer (score 3):

You should read about [formatters](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/0f/8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de/content.htm?no_cache=true), which are exactly what you require

Comment: I agree. But in this case the existing code was present in this way and I had to quickly just tweak it for one more condition.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
<Input value="{= (${order>/parts} === 'S' || ${order>/parts} === 'P') ? 'Yes' : 'No' }" />
<Input value="{= (${order>/parts} === 'S' &amp;&amp; ${order>/stock} === 'A') ? 'Yes' : 'No' }" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It helped me too.

In my case it was using icons:

```
<Button icon="{= ${Approved} === true ? 'sap-icon://accept' : 'sap-icon://approve'}" press="onApproveProduct" />
```